# Problem with left outer join

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables.

**Table 1 :** `t_atc_list`

```
id | a_name | s_title | r_name
------------------------------
80 | ss     | 128     | 5
```

Where s_title & r_name is foreign key.

**Table 2 :** `t_s_list`

```
s_id | title
-------------
128  | Song Title
```

I want have used left join query on this..to select all values of 't_atc_list' if it mightbe in 't_s_list'..

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT t.s_title, s.title from t_atc_list t LEFT OUTER JOIN t_s_list s ON t.s_title=s.s_id");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

While if I use right join its working..

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT t.s_title, s.title from t_s_list s RIGHT OUTER JOIN t_atc_list t ON t.s_title=s.s_id");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

**Whats the reason left join is not working but right join is going well? And I think both the queries are identical than whats the problem?**

Comment: And what is the error you are getting(if any)?

Comment: I am not getting any output...

Comment: The query looks fine, did you try running it in mysql directly (without php)?

Comment: Yes then also problem is same. no output

Comment: Aditii, can you run the query in a command line to verify that this query should return results? It sounds like there's nothing to return.

**edit:** It sounds like a data issue, aditii.

Comment: Which version of MySQL you are using?

Comment: Are s_title and s_id the same data type?  Sure s_title foreign key is defined in t_atc_list table?

Answer (score 0):

This is a strictly data related issue you have there, your SQL syntax is correct, but your data must not line up.

For a visualization of SQL, look here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Also if you do a right join, that means you are simply getting data from the 2nd table, and nulls in the first. I am just guessing here as I see no real data examples.